# How to update country borders in matplotlib.basemap?

Tags: matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I'm using basemap-1.0.7 and generated an image of Africa with the drawcountries() method.

The border between Sudan and South Sudan is missing. Does someone know how to update this country borders?